# Drawing a circle on a pictureBox from another winform

Tags: c#, winforms

I have two winforms in my application.  One of the forms has a picturebox with a jpg loaded of our building plan.  The main form has code that does facial recognition identifying people coming into certain areas.  I have been asked to modify this program to show an identified individual's location on the building plan.  I have a database that has all the X,Y coordinates of the locations that should map to the building plan image.  I have looked around and tried to find some code that will draw a circle on the map at the X,Y coordinates as the person progresses through areas of the building by erasing all the existing circles and updating this new one.  So on the map form I put in the following code:

```
public void DrawCircle(int x, int y)
    {
        Graphics gf = pictureBox1.CreateGraphics();
        gf.DrawEllipse(new Pen(Color.Red), new Rectangle(x, y, 400, 400));
        pictureBox1.Refresh();
    }
```

Then from the update method (right now a button click for testing) on the main form I call this method on the map form.  The method gets called, but the circle doesn't show up on the form.  I have tried both Refresh and Invalidate and neither method seems to draw the circle on the image.

I haven't done winforms development for years, so I'm sure I am missing some plumbing somewhere.  Here is the code on the mainform:

```
LocationMap map = new LocationMap();

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    //set up signalR
    UserName = "MovementHub1";
    ConnectAsync();
    //show the map screen
    map.Show();
    map.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
    ...
```

Then in a click event (for testing right now) I have this code:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        map.DrawCircle(340, 258);
    }
```

Once I get the circle drawn on the other form, then I will remove the code from the click event and move it another event that does the updating on the location.  If it's possible, I would like to put a label by the circle that has the person's name.  Right now this is a proof of concept, I just need help getting the circle on the form to start with.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried It out by myself and came up with that:

**Form1.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace StackoverflowHelp
{
  public partial class Form1 : Form
  {
    Form2 form = new Form2();

    public Form1()
    {
      InitializeComponent();
      form.Show();
    }

    private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      form.DrawCircle(100, 100);
    }
  }
}
```

**Form2.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace StackoverflowHelp
{
  public partial class Form2 : Form
  {
    public Form2()
    {
      InitializeComponent();

      DrawCircle(10, 10);
    }

    public void DrawCircle(int x, int y)
    {
      Graphics gf = Graphics.FromImage(pictureBox1.Image);
      gf.DrawEllipse(new Pen(Color.Red), new Rectangle(x, y, 20, 20));
      gf.Dispose();
      pictureBox1.Refresh();
      pictureBox1.Invalidate();
      pictureBox1.Update();
    }
  }
}
```

Instead of calling `CreateGraphics()` on the picturebox I created the graphics object using the current image.

Comment: Thank you Chuck Norris!  Looks like the graphics from image and the Update worked.

Comment: @john That graphics object needs to be disposed or put in a using-block.

Comment: Thanks @LarsTech, I did that.  Now how would I erase all the circles to refresh the image back to the originally loaded image?

Comment: @john You can't really erase graphics. Just create a graphic from the original image and start over.

Comment: Thanks @LarsTech I just reload the image since this is just a proof of concept and it appears to work fine.  Again, I appreciate the help.